# How to diasble scrolling (y-axle) with php

Tags: php, scroll

I am making an off canvas menu and I'm done with it. I jut want to disable the scrolbar after clicking it because it doesn't expand the whole page. But... I'm kinda stuck. I want to disable it vartically .I wanted to do it with PHP but all I got was:

```
<?php

if (sender.Id == "open-button")
{
 ; 
}

?>
```

The code of the button is:

```
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-bars  fa-3x" id="open-button"></a></li>
```

Help would be awesome because I'm kinda stuck

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it wrong. You cannot do that in PHP. You have to use javascript.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll try it that way. Thats probably why it wasn't working for me. Thank you!